Reduce $A_{TM}$ to Busy Beaver
I have a question described as follows from the Sipser's TOC textbook:

Let $\Gamma=\{0,1, \sqcup\}$ be the tape for all TMs in this problem. Define the busy beaver function $BB: N \rightarrow N$ as follows. For each value of $k$, consider all $k$-state TMs that halt when started with a blank tape. Let $BB(k)$ be the maximum number of $1$s that remain on the tape among all of these machines. Show that $BB$ is not a computable function.

I want to prove $BB$ is not computable by reducing $A_{TM}$ to $BB$. I found a similar question but proven using a different approach. My thought is given $M$, I know the number of states $|Q|$, let's denote it as $k$. Hence, $BB(k)$ tells me the maximum number of $1$s that remain on the tape among all $k$-state machines that halt when started with a blank tape.
If I construct a decider for $A_{TM}$, is $BB(k)$ an upper bound of steps that $M(w)$ could possibly run if it were to halt?

I don't see why it would be. Note there are (at least) two common versions of the busy beaver function, one where the "busy-ness" is determined by the run-time (to which your proposed solution immediately applies) and another that you are using where it is determined by the number of ones on the tape at the end (which will require some extra thinking).

Actually, your approach is also slightly complicated by the presence of the input $w$, whereas BB applies to machines run on blank input. This can be taken care of by constructing an auxiliary machine M' that first writes $w$ to a blank tape, returns home then dispatches $M$. (And the bigger issue with the number of ones vs runtime can also be solved by constructing an auxiliary machine.)

@spaceisdarkgreen can you give me any hint if you were to solve this problem

This answer to the question you linked is the solution I had in mind that is for your version of BB.

My question is a little different because $A_{TM}$ is not the halting problem but the problem that decides whether $M$ accepts $w$. $BB(k)$ is the maximum number of $1$s that remain on the tape of all k-state TMs that halt when started with a blank tape, therefore, I don't know how this would help with deciding whether w is accepted by M

I wrote an answer. It's really not very different from that solution. Sure, they are reducing from the blank tape halting problem rather than $A_{TM}$ but 1)  $A_{TM}$ reduces to the blank tape halting problem (just construct a machine that simulates $M$ on $w$ and accepts if it accepts and enters an infinite loop if it rejects) 2) more importantly, the solution really just relies on simulating a computation of some sort, and we can just swap out "simulate $M$ on a blank tape" with "simulate $M$ on $w$".

As noted in the comments, no $BB(k)$ is not an upper bound on the number of steps for any halting computation on a machine with $k$ states. You can do the trick given in this answer to the same question you linked though, which I'll paraphrase:

Given a TM $M$ and input $w$, you can compute a TM $M'$ that, on a blank input, simulates $M$ on $w$, keeping track of how many steps, and if and when that computation finishes after some number of steps $t$, it cleans up and writes $t$ 1's to its tape and halts. Then, you can compute $k$, the number of states in $M'$, and then $BB(k).$ Then you can actually simulate $M$ on $w$ accept if that computation accepts within $BB(k)$ steps, otherwise reject. The machine $M$ running on $w$ cannot halt after more than $BB(k)$ steps, since if it did, $M'$ would be a $k$-state machine that on a blank input, halts with more than $BB(k)$ ones on the tape, contradicting the definition of $BB.$

